# How to store and recall a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on an Item, I am storing a variable `url` but I have many items, so

**HTML**

```
<div class="item">
  <span id="0" class="video" data-vimeoid="http://vimeo.com/XXX"></span>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <span id="1" class="video" data-vimeoid="http://vimeo.com/SSS"></span>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <span id="2" class="video" data-vimeoid="http://vimeo.com/ZZZ"></span>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.item:not(.expanded)', function() {
  $(".item").removeClass("expanded");
  $(this).addClass("expanded");
  var videoSpan =  $(this).find("span.video");
  var url = videoSpan.data("vimeoid");
  if(url){
    var tokens = url.split("/");
    var id = tokens[3];
    var iframe = $('<iframe/>', {
     'frameborder' : 0,
     'class' : 'tide embed-responsive-item',
     'src' : 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/'+ id + '?api=1&player_id=player1 webkitAllowFullScreen  mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen',
    });
    videoSpan.replaceWith(iframe);
    $(".item:not(.expanded) span.video").empty().html('<span class="video" data-vimeoid="' + url + '"></span>');
  }
});
```

This is emptying any previous span where I loaded the video but the `URL variable` is what it will be found in the current clicked item while I want to restore the original.

Comment: What do you mean by `This is removing any previous loaded video but the URL variable is what it will be found in the current clicked item while I want to restore the original.`?

Comment: Do you want to retain the `data-vimeoid` present in the HTML in thie line `(".item:not(.is-expanded) span.video").empty().append('<span class="video" data-vimeoid="' + url + '"></span>';);`? Also, should 'is-expanded' and 'expanded' be the same class?

Comment: Shouldn't `.item:not(.is-expanded)` be instead `.item:not(.expanded)`??? And you are missing former `$` in `(".item:not(.is-expanded) span.video")` and btw, instead of using `.empty().append(...)`, use `.html(...)`

Comment: @void by removing I mean empty, see the code with an empty() ?

Comment: @DebanshuKundu sry was a type, is-expanded is indeed the same as expanded, updated.

Comment: @A.Wolff apologies, was just a typo here. Ok for html, but what I'm looking for is regardless of it. but yes i will use .html() actually

Comment: `$("this)` might causing error

Comment: restore the original ?? what do you mean what is the original?

Comment: @Lupin it's all written in the question: "When I click on an Item, I am storing a variable url but I have many items"

Comment: @rob.m , Sorry but did go over the question several times and still did not get it.... i understand that you get the url of the item that was jst clicked but did not understand your last sentence and to which original you want to restore it to

Comment: @rob.m you should show us the HTML you expect after a click on XXX then after a click on SSS, then maybe we can decipher your code. But Dominique Fortin is probably right in saying you should keep your URL information in the DIV tag and not the span which you smash and attempt to restore (from what I understand.)

Comment: @AlexisWilke eventually i gave up with the array bit, I am now simply loading the iframe INTO the span and not replacing it and emptying the span when I click on another item. This way I won't destroy the data attribute and always have it available to read when I generate my variable URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved it like this: basically I load the `iframe` into the `span` and not replace it, then I empty the `span` where I load the `iframe`, and I reload it each time.

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.item:not(.is-expanded)', function() {
  $(".item div.video").empty();
  var videoSpan =  $(this).find("div.video");
  var url = videoSpan.data("vimeoid");

  if (url) {
    var tokens = url.split("/");
    var id = tokens[3];
    var iframe = $('<iframe/>', {
      'frameborder' : 0,
      'class' : 'tide embed-responsive-item',
      'src' : 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/'+ id + '?api=1 webkitAllowFullScreen  mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen'
    });
    videoSpan.html(iframe);
  }
});
```

Comment: Cool, so I think I understood what you were trying to do. Note that a `<span>` is an inline tag which should not include a block tag such as `<iframe>`. Not too important in HTML 5, but something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an id attribute in each div tag with your video.  Then you use that id to stored previous url in an array that would look like

```
[{"id": 1, "url": "http://..." }, ...]
...


<div class="item" id="1">...

...

var previous = [];

...

previous.push({"id":'1', "url":url});
```

Comment: Thing is that div is dynamic, therefore i cannot manually insert an ID, or better I can but I need to generate it for each of my items

Comment: how would I generate an individual ID for each item and then call what you did here then?

Comment: @rob.m I would used something like "{...}.id = ''+(new Date).getTime();"